# how to join two table in database

Tags: mysql

I want query for join two table in single other table.

PhpMyadmin database

Table One

```
  c_id            name
   ------------------
   a                1
   b                2
   c                .
   d                4
```

Table Two

```
  m_id           name
   ------------------
   a                1
   b                2
   c                .
   d                4
   e                .
   f                .
```

One and Two Joined

```
    c_id             m_id       name        
    --------------------------------------
     a                a        
     a                b        
     a                c  
     b                a  
     b                b  
     b                c
```

i want help to join two table ..(i think Wordpress store data in this kind of format, it uses few tables and store any number field related to post/category within those tables).any help/idea to solve this problem would be appreciated.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to `JOIN` them in a `SELECT` query (as in, extract data but not change existing data in the database) then you could do a simple join query with this structure:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
    JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.a_id
```